# how to create a cookie and add to http response from inside my service layer?

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-mvc

I am creating a custom authentication service in my spring mvc application:

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements AuthenticationService {

   @Autowired
   UserService userService;

   @Override
   public void login(String email, String password) {

      boolean isValid = userService.isValidLogin(email, password);

      if(isValid) {
          // ??? create a session cookie and add to http response
      }

   }

}
```

How can I create and add the cookie to the response?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Spring MVC you get the HtppServletResponce object by default .

```
   @RequestMapping("/myPath.htm")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
            //Do service call passing the response
    return new ModelAndView("CustomerAddView");
    }

//Service code
Cookie myCookie =
  new Cookie("name", "val");
  response.addCookie(myCookie);
```

Answer (score 31):

Following @Aravind's answer with more details

```
@RequestMapping("/myPath.htm")
public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    myServiceMethodSettingCookie(request, response);        //Do service call passing the response
    return new ModelAndView("CustomerAddView");
}

// service method
void myServiceMethodSettingCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    final String cookieName = "my_cool_cookie";
    final String cookieValue = "my cool value here !";  // you could assign it some encoded value
    final Boolean useSecureCookie = false;
    final int expiryTime = 60 * 60 * 24;  // 24h in seconds
    final String cookiePath = "/";

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);

    cookie.setSecure(useSecureCookie);  // determines whether the cookie should only be sent using a secure protocol, such as HTTPS or SSL

    cookie.setMaxAge(expiryTime);  // A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.

    cookie.setPath(cookiePath);  // The cookie is visible to all the pages in the directory you specify, and all the pages in that directory's subdirectories

    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Related docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html

Answer (score 9):

A cookie is a object with key value pair to store information related to the customer. Main objective is to personalize the customer's experience.

An utility method can be created like

```
private Cookie createCookie(String cookieName, String cookieValue) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(MAX_AGE_SECONDS);
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setSecure(true);
    return cookie;
}
```

If storing important information then we should alsways put setHttpOnly so that the cookie cannot be accessed/modified via javascript. setSecure is applicable if you are want cookies to be accessed only over https protocol.

using above utility method you can add cookies to response as

```
Cookie cookie = createCookie("name","value");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a new cookie, use [HttpServletResponse.addCookie(Cookie)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29). The [Cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) is pretty much a key value pair taking a name and value as strings on construction.

Comment: Btw, I don't recommend you do this to create your own authentication scheme.