# What is the return type of a cookie?

Tags: java, rest, cookies, jwt

I'm very new to Java Web programming and I am trying to write a method to authenticate a user, store a token in a cookie, and pass them onto the next page. I'm hung up on what the return type of the authentication should be. Should it return a Cookie object directly as the return value of `authenticateUser()`?

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response authenticateUser(@FormParam("username") String username, 
                                 @FormParam("password") String password) {

    try {

        // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
        authenticate(username, password);

        // Issue a token for the user
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "----ABOUT TO LOG TOKEN TO WILDFLY");
        String token = issueToken(username,"http://example.com","userToken",msInHour); //returns JWT token
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "----LOGGING TOKEN TO WILDFLY: ",token);
        // Return the token on the response
        //return Response.ok(token).build();
        Response.createCookie(createCookie(token,username)).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        _logger.log(Level.INFO, "----ERROR in AuthService:",e);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
    }      
}

private Cookie createCookie(String token,String uname){
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889679/how-to-create-a-cookie-and-add-to-http-response-from-inside-my-service-layer
    final Boolean useSecureCookie = true;
    final int expiryTime = 60 * 60 * 24;  // 24h in seconds
    final String cookiePath = "/";

    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("example.com", uname+"_"+token);
    cookie.setSecure(useSecureCookie);  // determines whether the cookie should only be sent using a secure protocol, such as HTTPS or SSL
    cookie.setMaxAge(expiryTime);  // A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
    cookie.setPath(cookiePath);  // The cookie is visible to all the pages in the directory you specify, and all the pages in that directory's subdirectories
    return cookie;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean what's the return type of a cookie? That's like saying "what's the return type of a database" - a cookie is merely a client-side storage mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Jersey as your backend framework so you need to look at their documentation to see how setting cookies works. And no, you more than probably can't return the plain cookie as the browser won't understand it as such, especially since you're "producing" JSON.

[How to set cookie in Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231156/how-to-set-cookie-in-jersey).

As you can see from the accepted answer the `Response` object should have a separate method for setting cookies, aptly named `cookie()`.